# Why is the "RedisStreamCommands" interface not found in my project?

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I am trying to import the `RedisStreamCommands`. I was enable to import it, but I can import RedisCommands. I think it needs dependency. I don't know what was that, please help me out.

```
RedisCommands<String, String> syncCommands = connection.sync();
RedisStreamCommands<String, String> streamCommands = connection.sync();
syncCommands.set("key_1", "Hello, Redis!");
Map<String, String> body =  Collections.singletonMap("key", "value");
String messageId = streamCommands.xadd("my-stream", body);
```

I have tried like this: it was shown error on RedisStreamCommands.

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import io.lettuce.core.RedisClient;
import io.lettuce.core.RedisURI;
import io.lettuce.core.api.StatefulRedisConnection;
import io.lettuce.core.api.sync.*;
import io.lettuce.core.api.sync.RedisCommands;
import io.lettuce.core.cluster.RedisClusterClient;
import io.lettuce.core.cluster.api.StatefulRedisClusterConnection;
import io.lettuce.core.cluster.api.sync.RedisAdvancedClusterCommands;

public class LettuceDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.create("redis://15m4madm4bd6ypfqtc353wfq4q292brk@expeditious-ironwood-6027.redisgreen.net:11042/0");
        StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection = redisClient.connect();
        RedisCommands<String, String> syncCommands = connection.sync();
        RedisStreamCommands<String, String> streamCommands = connection.sync();
        syncCommands.set("key_1", "Hello, Redis!");
        Map<String, String> body =  Collections.singletonMap("key", "value");
        String messageId = streamCommands.xadd("my-stream", body);

        connection.close();
        redisClient.shutdown();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interface [`io.lettuce.core.api.sync.RedisStreamCommands`](https://lettuce.io/core/release/api/io/lettuce/core/api/sync/RedisStreamCommands.html) was introduced in Redis release 5.1; most likely you are using an earlier version which does not contain it.

Basically, you should therefore check your classpath and the version of Redis and adjust it - if necessary - to version *5.1+*. You can obtain it from here: https://lettuce.io/docs or check the documentation for further details.

Hope it helps.